# Java: Optimizing an application using asynchronous programming

Tags: java, asynchronous, optimization

I have to modify a dropwizard application to improve its running time. Basically, this application receives around 3 million URLs daily and downloads and parses them to detect for malicious content. The problem is that the application is only able to process 1 million URLs. When I looked at the application I found that it is making a lot of sequential calls. I would like some suggestion on how can I improve the application by making it asynchronous or other techniques.

Required code is as follows:-

```
/* Scheduler */
private long triggerDetection(String startDate, String endDate) {
for (UrlRequest request : urlRequests) {
                if (!validateRequests.isWhitelisted(request)) {
                    ContentDetectionClient.detectContent(request);
                }
            }
}

/* Client */
public void detectContent(UrlRequest urlRequest){
        Client client = new Client();
        URI uri = buildUrl(); /* It returns the URL of this dropwizard application's resource method provided below */

        ClientResponse response = client.resource(uri)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, urlRequest);

        Integer status = response.getStatus();
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
            log.info("Completed request for url: {}", urlRequest.getUrl());

        }else{
            log.error("request failed for url: {}", urlRequest.getUrl());
        }
    }

    private URI buildUrl() {
        return UriBuilder
                .fromPath(uriConfiguration.getUrl())
                .build();
    }

/* Resource Method */
 @POST
    @Path("/pageDetection")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    /**
     * Receives the url of the publisher, crawls the content of that url, applies a detector to check if the content is malicious.
     * @returns returns the probability of the page being malicious
     * @throws throws exception if the crawl call failed
     **/
    public DetectionScore detectContent(UrlRequest urlRequest) throws Exception {

        return contentAnalysisOrchestrator.detectContentPage(urlRequest);
    }

/* Orchestrator */
public DetectionScore detectContentPage(UrlRequest urlRequest) {
        try {

            Pair<Integer, HtmlPage> response =  crawler.rawLoad(urlRequest.getUrl());
            String content =   response.getValue().text();

            DetectionScore detectionScore = detector.getProbability(urlRequest.getUrl(), content);
            contentDetectionResultDao.insert(urlRequest.getAffiliateId(), urlRequest.getUrl(),detectionScore.getProbability()*1000,
                    detectionScore.getRecommendation(), urlRequest.getRequestsPerUrl(), -1, urlRequest.getCreatedAt() );

            return detectionScore;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Error while analyzing the url : {}", e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

I was thinking of following approaches:-

- Instead of calling the dropwizard resource method via POST, I call `orchestrator.detectContent(urlRequest)` directly from scheduler.
- The orchestrator can return detectionScore and I'll store all the detectScores in a map/table and perform batch database insertion instead of individual insertion as in the present code.

I would like some comments on the above approaches and possibly other techniques by which I can improve the running time. Also, I just read about Java asynchronous programming but can't seem to understand how to use it in the above code, so would like some help with this also.

Thanks.

Edit:
I can think of two bottlenecks:

- Downloading of webpage
- Insertion of result in to the database (Database is located in another system)
- It seems that processing is performed 1 URL at a time

The system has 8 GB of memory out of which 4 GB appears to be free

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7843       4496       3346          0        193       2339
-/+ buffers/cache:       1964       5879 
Swap:         1952        489       1463
```

CPU usage is also minimal:

```
top - 13:31:19 up 19 days, 15:39,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 215 total,   1 running, 214 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.5%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.4%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8031412k total,  4605196k used,  3426216k free,   198040k buffers
Swap:  1999868k total,   501020k used,  1498848k free,  2395344k cached
```

Comment: "Measure twice, optimize once" is what the old folks used to say when trying to tackle performance problems.

Comment: First thing to check: your CPU utilization. If it's at or near 100%, asynchronous processing won't help you.

Comment: Are you processing 1 URL (from the clients) at a time, or are you performing bulk operations? How many concurrent requests do you get from your clients. I'm wondering what level of utilisation your system has. Optimising a single request path won't necessarily help, if the system itself is at, or close to capacity.

Comment: CPU usage is minimal. There seems to be two bottlenecks: 1) Downloading of webpage 2) Insertion in to the database (database is located in another machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by Davide's (great) answer here is an example, easy way to parallelise this using [simple-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react) (I library I wrote).  Note it is slightly different, using the client to drive the concurrency on the server.

**Example**

```
LazyReact streamBuilder = new LazyReact(15,15);

streamBuilder.fromIterable(urlRequests)
      .filter(urlReq->!validateRequests.isWhitelisted(urlReq))
      .forEach(request -> {
           ContentDetectionClient.detectContent(request);
       });
```

**Explanation**

It looks like you can drive the concurrency from the client. Which means you can distribute the work across threads on the serverside with no additional work. In this example we are making 15 concurrent requests, but you could set it somewhere close to max the server can handle. Your application is IO Bound, so you can use a lot of threads to drive performance.

simple-react works as a Stream of Futures. So here we create an Async task for each call to the ContentDetection client. We have 15 threads available, so 15 calls can be made at once to the server.

**Java 7**

There is a backport of JDK 8 functionality for Java 7 called [StreamSupport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) and you can also backport Lambda Expressions via [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).

To implement the same solution with CompletableFutures we can create a Future Task for each eligible URL. **UPDATE** I don't think we need to batch them, we can use the Executor to limit the number of active futures. We merely need to join on them all at the end.

```
   Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxActive);//15 threads
   List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures= new ArrayList<>();

   for (UrlRequest request : urlRequests) {
            if (!validateRequests.isWhitelisted(request)) {
                futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->ContentDetectionClient.detectContent(request), exec));
            }
        }
 CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray())
                      .join();
```

Comment: I think that simple react nor any other multithreading tecnique will be useful to improve performances if the bottleneck is the network bandwith. As you can see from the question the cpu time is close to 0, so only I/O operations are composing the process time execution. I am waiting for info about downloaded gigabytes and bandwith too see if it could be useful to split the actual program in different threads or not.

Comment: Forgot to mention. Server jas Java 7 :(

Comment: Fear not - I've been looking at StreamSupport  and it has CompletableFuture included. I'll update with an example of how to do this with raw CompletableFutures (which will work on Java 7) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

Comment: Thanks for the solution @JohnMcClean. I'll try the solutions mentioned in this thread tomorrow and will get back to you guys. Again, thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO You mean if there is available bandwidth for more concurrent downloads? If they are doing one at a time currently, there should be.

Comment: Yes. Probably if the guaranteed bandwith is at least 10Mb/s there should be enough to handle 3M pages of 30 kb each. From my calculations 3M * 30K will use continuously a band of 8.3 Mb/s. If the band is 100Mb/s or 1Gb/s there  will be enough space to allow increasing performances with parallels download.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMcClean. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

First check where you loose majority of the time.

I suppose that most of the time is lost downloading the urls.

If downloading urls take more than 90% of the time probably you can't improve your applications because the bottleneck is not java but your network.

---

**Consider the following only if downloading time is under network capabilities**

If the downloading time is not so high you probably can try to improve your performances. A standard approach is to use a producers consumers chain. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for details.

Basically you can split your work as follow:

```
Downloading --> Parsing --> Saving
```

Downloading is a producer, parsing is a consumer for downloading process and a producer for saving process and saving is a consumer.

Each step can be executed by a different number of threads. For example you can have 3 downloading threads, 5 parsing threads and 1 saving thread.

---

Edited after comments

As supposed the bottleneck is not cpu time so it is not important to make intervention on the java code.

If you know how many GigaBytes you download each day is possible to see if they are close to the maximum bandwith of your network.

If this happens there are different possibilities:

- Request for compressed content using `Content-Encoding: gzip` (so reducing used bandwith)
- Split your application between different nodes working on different networks (so split the bandwith between different networks)
- update your bandwith (so increase bandwith for your network)
- Be sure to download only requested content (so no javascript, images, css and so on if not requested) (to minimize usage of bandwith)
- A combination of the previous solutions

Comment: Alternatively you can check CPU load, if it's close to maximum already, multiple threads won't buy you much.

Comment: Yes but it seams difficult for this scenario where there is a massive url download. Generally I/O operations are the bottleneck, not cpu calculations. But you are right!

Comment: CPU usage is minimal. There seems to be two bottlenecks: 1) Downloading of webpage 2) Insertion in to the database (database is located in another machine)

Comment: Check network usage over internet. Probably the bottleneck is not in the internal network (so not accessing the db) but for external network (downloading pages). If you are close to maximum bandwith of your internet connection you can only check if you are requesting the zipped version of content or not.

Comment: Nice solution. I'd also recommend highlighting which parts are CPU Bound (parsing) versus I/O bound (Downloading & Saving) as that can be used to determine the number of threads that should be allocated to each. One possibility would be for the Parsing section to continue to use the downloading thread once it completes, before passing an async task to the Saving thread pool. Good fit for CompletableFutures here (or even simple-react).

Comment: I think the processing is performed 1 URL at at time. Scheduler sends a URL to the client which then goes through the following cycle POST Query->Fetching->Detection->Insertion into database. Is there any technique I can make this process async?

Comment: The problem is not that this process is done by only one thread. If you loose all your time downloading the data you can't improve to much also splitting between different threads. Check instead updated response to see other techniques to improve it.

Comment: Post the following numbers if you have: gigabytes downloaded each day, guaranteed bandwith

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I checked the updated answer too. The points you mentioned are very helpful. Waiting for more solutions before I can accept an answer.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Bandwidth information can be provided tomorrow only as I don't have install permission on the server. Have asked the admins to install 'iftop' on the server.

Comment: And you can check the size of download pages per day? Is a data in your possession?

Comment: The pages are not saved in any datastore. Pages are downloaded in memory and all the computations are performed in memory only.