# CompletableFuture in the Android Support Library?

Tags: android, java-8

So I was migrating an Android Studio project to Java 8, Android API level 24 and the Jack toolchain today to check out the new features, especially lambdas and `CompletableFuture`.

Unfortunately, `CompletableFuture` seems to be available only from API level 24 on (my minimum API level for that project being 16).

Do you know of any plans on bringing `CompletableFuture` to the Android support library? It looks like a nice solution for the Promises pattern.

Comment: I don't know about Google's plans for the support library. But note that the `streamsupport` project also provides a backport of `CompletableFuture` in its `streamsupport-cfuture` module. This runs (and get's regularly tested) on Android and all Java versions >= 6. See https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

Comment: @StefanZobel If you make your comment an answer to my question I will accept it as best answer (since it covers Android)

Comment: Thanks. Have done that. See below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) project provides a backport of `CompletableFuture` in its `streamsupport-cfuture` component which can be used for Android development, supported on all devices.

Either use

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-cfuture:1.7.4'
}
```

or the more modern [android-retrofuture](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrofuture) fork for Android Studio >= 3.x

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retrofuture:1.7.4'
}
```

if you can use Android Studio 3.x and above.

The new Java 12 exception handling methods for CompletableFuture [JDK-8211010](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211010) have been integrated in release 1.7.0

For users who want a minimal dependency footprint there is also a 105 KiB `minifuture` variant which is a "stripped to the bones" version of `streamsupport-cfuture`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-minifuture:1.7.4'
}
```

This has no dependencies and provides only the minimum API necessary to use `CompletableFuture` and nothing else (no Streams, no public ForkJoinPool and such).

Answer (score 6):

`streamsupport` library mentioned in Stefan Zobel's answer was forked especially for Android Studio >=3.0 desugar toolchain, please check [android-retrofuture](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrofuture)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need all features of the `CompletableFuture` (e.g. result chaining), you can use this class (Kotlin):

```
/**
 * A backport of Java `CompletableFuture` which works with old Androids.
 */
class CompletableFutureCompat<V> : Future<V> {
    private sealed class Result<out V> {
        abstract val value: V
        class Ok<V>(override val value: V) : Result<V>()
        class Error(val e: Throwable) : Result<Nothing>() {
            override val value: Nothing
                get() = throw e
        }
        object Cancel : Result<Nothing>() {
            override val value: Nothing
                get() = throw CancellationException()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Offers the completion result for [result].
     *
     * If this queue is not empty, the future is completed.
     */
    private val completion = LinkedBlockingQueue<Result<V>>(1)
    /**
     * Holds the result of the computation. Takes the item from [completion] upon running and provides it as a result.
     */
    private val result = FutureTask<V> { completion.peek()!!.value }
    /**
     * If not already completed, causes invocations of [get]
     * and related methods to throw the given exception.
     *
     * @param ex the exception
     * @return `true` if this invocation caused this CompletableFuture
     * to transition to a completed state, else `false`
     */
    fun completeExceptionally(ex: Throwable): Boolean {
        val offered = completion.offer(Result.Error(ex))
        if (offered) {
            result.run()
        }
        return offered
    }

    /**
     * If not already completed, completes this CompletableFuture with
     * a [CancellationException].
     *
     * @param mayInterruptIfRunning this value has no effect in this
     * implementation because interrupts are not used to control
     * processing.
     *
     * @return `true` if this task is now cancelled
     */
    override fun cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean {
        val offered = completion.offer(Result.Cancel)
        if (offered) {
            result.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
        }
        return offered
    }

    /**
     * If not already completed, sets the value returned by [get] and related methods to the given value.
     *
     * @param value the result value
     * @return `true` if this invocation caused this CompletableFuture
     * to transition to a completed state, else `false`
     */
    fun complete(value: V): Boolean {
        val offered = completion.offer(Result.Ok(value))
        if (offered) {
            result.run()
        }
        return offered
    }

    override fun isDone(): Boolean = completion.isNotEmpty()

    override fun get(): V = result.get()

    override fun get(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit): V = result.get(timeout, unit)

    override fun isCancelled(): Boolean = completion.peek() == Result.Cancel
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Related and perhaps useful for you: [Java: Optimizing an application using asynchronous programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740637/java-optimizing-an-application-using-asynchronous-programming/32741591#32741591)

This answer is about CompletableFuture on Java 7 using the library mentioned in the comment above, not on Android. However, the lib's documentation states that it works on Android. I haven't used it myself though.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Does not work on Android.   Requires API 24 still, which is the original issue.

Comment: @Bisclavret I was talking about [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) which is mentioned in that answer (specifically the `streamsupport-cfuture` component). That one only requires API level 14 or 15 and it works very well.