# Alternative to CompletableFuture API17

Tags: java, android

Is there an alternative to CompletableFuture that I could use along with Android SDK API 17?

In my app I am sending some form data to the server, plus a security token that expires every 5 minutes and I need to check if the token has been expired in every http request and if yes, I need to ask for the new token and "after that" send my form data again.

In Angular I used Promises and everything went on well. But in Java, and specially Android API 17 I have no idea how to do this.
Please guide me. 
Thanks.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221673/completablefuture-in-the-android-support-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it by passing a function to an AsyncTask

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, the question and answer is 3 years old. Anyone ending up in this page must look for another solution. In that time, AsyncTask was the solution.

Comment: After deprecation of AsyncTask, I start searching for alternatives and found CompletableFuture. But CompletableFuture is only available for API version 24 and above. But there are some backport libraries available in Github.

Comment: I think Kotlin coroutines or RxJava are better alternatives.